# Overlapping marker google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlapping

I need to put on my cartography database. I set the table and page for the acquisition of the coordinates and function properly, as well as the vision of the map.
Now in 8000 many records are in the same coordinates. How do I create the overlapping?

```
<html > 
 <head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Mappa Veicoli</title> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?                   
       key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
        type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[ 

var customIcons = { 
  FRANCIA: { 
    icon: '../immig/bandiere/blue_MarkerA.png' 
  }, 
  GERMANIA: { 
    icon: './immig/bandiere/pink_MarkerA.png' 
  }, 
  USA: { 
    icon: '../immig/bandiere/darkgreen_MarkerA.png' 
  } 
  , 
  SPAGNA: { 
    icon: '../immig/bandiere/green_MarkerA.png' 
  } 
}; 

function load() { 
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.444, 14.2 ), 
    zoom: 13, 
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
  }); 
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; 

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
  downloadUrl("xmleicoli.php", function(data) { 
    var xml = data.responseXML; 
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
      var cognome = markers[i].getAttribute("Cognome"); 
      var nome = markers[i].getAttribute("Nome"); 
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("Nazione"); 
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("Residenza"); 

      var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), 
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))); 
      var html = "<b>" + cognome + "," + nome + "</b> <br/>" +       
           address; 
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {}; 
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        map: map, 
        position: point, 
        icon: icon.icon 
      }); 
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html); 
    } 
  }); 
          } 

  function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    infoWindow.setContent(html); 
    infoWindow.open(map, marker); 
  }); 
    } 

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
   var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
      new XMLHttpRequest; 

  request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (request.readyState == 4) { 
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
      callback(request, request.status); 
    } 
  }; 

  request.open('GET', url, true); 
  request.send(null); 
} 

    function doNothing() {} 

//]]> 

 </script> 

 </head> 

 <body onload="load()"> 
<div id="map" style="width: 1200px; height:800px"></div> 
 </body> 

     </html>
```

Comment: `function doNothing() {}` - why?

Comment: It is used by the `downloadUrl` function when the request is complete.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to move slightly each marker so that they do not overlap each other and the for indicate that there are more marker grouped you can use a marker cluster you can see many examples in StackOverflow

For the marker yuo can set the position with a small difference in lat, lng eg adding + 0.00001 for every marker in the same original place

Comment: Thanks for the answers,
I tried adding 0.000001 but the markers are too close and not easy to distinguish.
I found OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier but do not understand how to implement the code.

Comment: 0.00001 not 0.000001  one zero in less. otherwise teh markers are too close, or 0.00005 if the result is better..

Comment: I also tried to add 0.00010 , but the difference is so small you can not see because they are about 8000 records why I had thought OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Comment: When adding the offset to lat/long using 0.000001 (or some other offset greater or less) you will need to consider the map zoom level as well. The offset of 0.000001 might look fine, and solve your problem, at zoom level 15, but it may not look good at zoom level 10. Just something to consider.